# Using google cloud ml gpu on python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.6, pytorch, python-3.7, google-cloud-ml

I am trying to run a ML model on google cloud ML. I am using pytorch and want to use the GPU. Using the standard Python3.6 version installed on the Google cloud VM, I get an error described below and tried solving it by upgrading the Python version to Python 3.7, but this version does not recognize the GPU that comes with the Google cloud VM.

Whenever I run my code (which works when ran locally) on the Google cloud VM (based on Python3.6) I get the error

```
python: symbol lookup error: /home/julsoles/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_python.so: undefined symbol: PySlice_Unpack
```

Trying to find a solution online, I figured out that this was an issue with the version of Python 3.6 and the only solution was to upgrade my version of Python.

I was able to upgrade my version of Python to Python3.7 in the Google Cloud VM and can run code with this new version using the command Python3.7 file.py.
Now, the issue is that whenever I run code using this version of Python, the VM does not recognize the GPU that comes with the system. I get the error

> File "pred.py", line 75, in 
>       predict(model_list, test_dataset)   File "pred.py", line 28, in predict
>       x = Variable(torch.from_numpy(x).float()).cuda()   File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/cuda/**init**.py",
>   line 161, in _lazy_init
>       _check_driver()   File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/cuda/**init**.py",
>   line 75, in _check_driver
>       raise AssertionError("Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled") AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled

Right now, the only solution I have found is to run my code just using cpu, but it is painstakingly slow. Is there any way to make Python3.7 recognize the GPU so that I can run my code using the GPU?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What version of PyTorch are you using? PyTorch is supported using Custom Containers in Cloud ML Engine. When you say  Google Cloud ML are you referring to Deep Learning VM image?

Comment: Yes, I ma referring to Deep Learning VM image and I was using torch-1.0.0

Comment: Would you mind sharing a minimal example to reproduce this behavior?